# Encrypt file and hide the code from "info body"

Tags: encryption, tcl

Is there any way protect tcl code by "info body" after the file encrypt and execute in tool?

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscate the code with [the compiler from the Tcl Dev Kit](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclcompiler); when the output of that is loaded in, it creates procedures whose contents cannot be inspected (by virtue of setting a special flag that turns off inspection). It also turns off a number of other related tools, such as the bytecode disassembler. (Curiously, this actually comes with a small performance penalty relative to standard Tcl; the special [bytecode loader library](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tbcload) is actually slower than Tcl's built-in bytecode compiler.)

That said, if you are *genuinely* worried about someone looking at your code, the only way to go is to not give users the code at all, but rather to host it as a service that they then just use remotely (with the clients not being subject to the same degree of protections).

And if you're not *that* worried, merely packing the code into a starkit (or other single-file distribution mechanism; there's a few options) is enough to stop all but the most determined of users, even with no further steps to conceal things.

Comment: Another approach that works for some code is using tclquadcode to make native code from your Tcl. That produces output that is… not easy to reverse engineer even with a classic disassembler, especially once the debugging information is stripped. But that currently only works for a subset of Tcl.